# Pandas - Join two DataFrame with condition ("between" condition)

Tags: pandas

it may be a complicated question

i have two table

Table1 :

```
   Day     Value
    1     1200             
    3     1300           
    4     1400            
    5     1500
```

Table2:

```
Day   Price
    1     5        
    3     8    
    4     6    
    5     9
```

Result that i want, Final_table

```
 Day       Value Price
    1     1200  NaN   
    3     1300  5
    4     1400  8
    5     1500  6
```

Explanation :

Join table2 to table1 on "Day" to make Final_table,but there is some condition

join Table2 row to Table1 row if fullfill this  condition:

```
Table2["Day"] >= Table1["Day"] - 2 and Table2["Day"] < Table1["Day"]
```

if there are two Table2 rows that fullfill the condition , join the row that have biggest "Day" only

Comment: why are rows shifted? price at day 3 is 8, not 5

Comment: when Table1['Day'] = 3 , then it will be joined with row from Table2 where  Table2['Day'] < 3 and Table2['Day']  => 3 - 2 , complicated right ?

Comment: yup, a little bit complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['day', 'value', 'price'])

for index, row in Table1.iterrows():
    tmp = Table2[(Table2["day"] >= row['day'] - 2) & (Table2["day"] < row['day'])]
    tmp['day'] = row['day']
    result = result.append(tmp[['price', 'day']].merge(row.to_frame().T, on='day'))

result

  day   price   value
0   3   5       1300
0   4   8       1400
0   5   8       1500
1   5   6       1500
```